# Salesforce Dates Incorrectly Formatting

Tags: apex, datetime, date

So I have an interesting issue with dates. Basically the format method for the month of December seems to be broken for 2014 and 2015. Running the following code for the years of 2015 and below fails in the assertion but 2016 seems to work correctly.

```
Date testDate = Date.newInstance(2014, 12, 30);
DateTime testDateTime = DateTime.newInstance(testDate, time.newInstance(0,0,0,0));
system.debug(testDate);
system.debug(testDateTime);
system.debug(Date.daysInMonth(2014,12));
system.assertEquals('December 2014', testDateTime.formatGmt('MMMM YYYY'), 'Salesforce dates are wrong?');
```

I am using the 30th December to avoid timezone issues and it seems to affect dates up to and around the 28th of December. A case has been raised with Salesforce but I was wondering if anybody else had seen this issue and/or resolved it?

EDIT---

Currently it returns December 2015 not December 2014.

Comment: what is testDateTime.formatGmt('MMMM YYYY') returning then? I'm curious.

Comment: It returns December 2015 (or the next year whatever the actual year is). I have updated the text to reflect this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This intrigued me and I did a bit of digging.

Turns out this is not a bug but a feature :).

Formatting using YYYY is NOT the same as yyyy.

Formatting using the YYYY notation would result in returning the "week year".
This is something that got introduced with java 7.

Here is the explanation from the documentation:

---

**Week Of Year and Week Year**

Values calculated for the WEEK_OF_YEAR field range from 1 to 53. The first week of a calendar year is the earliest seven day period starting on getFirstDayOfWeek() that contains at least getMinimalDaysInFirstWeek() days from that year. It thus depends on the values of getMinimalDaysInFirstWeek(), getFirstDayOfWeek(), and the day of the week of January 1. Weeks between week 1 of one year and week 1 of the following year (exclusive) are numbered sequentially from 2 to 52 or 53 (except for year(s) involved in the Julian-Gregorian transition).

The getFirstDayOfWeek() and getMinimalDaysInFirstWeek() values are initialized using locale-dependent resources when constructing a GregorianCalendar. The week determination is compatible with the ISO 8601 standard when getFirstDayOfWeek() is MONDAY and getMinimalDaysInFirstWeek() is 4, which values are used in locales where the standard is preferred. These values can explicitly be set by calling setFirstDayOfWeek() and setMinimalDaysInFirstWeek().

A week year is in sync with a WEEK_OF_YEAR cycle. All weeks between the first and last weeks (inclusive) have the same week year value. Therefore, the first and last days of a week year may have different calendar year values.

For example, January 1, 1998 is a Thursday. If getFirstDayOfWeek() is MONDAY and getMinimalDaysInFirstWeek() is 4 (ISO 8601 standard compatible setting), then week 1 of 1998 starts on December 29, 1997, and ends on January 4, 1998. The week year is 1998 for the last three days of calendar year 1997. If, however, getFirstDayOfWeek() is SUNDAY, then week 1 of 1998 starts on January 4, 1998, and ends on January 10, 1998; the first three days of 1998 then are part of week 53 of 1997 and their week year is 1997.

---

So using the yyyy for your formatting will solve your issue!